Electrical Issue replacing Exhaust Fan in Bathroom
I am replacing an old ventilation fan in my master bath. The old wiring was hidden inside a box tied up and inside the ceiling with the only removal option being to cut wires. This means I could not see how it was previously wired.
I have power running to the box in the ceiling, which continues from there to power some wall outlets in my living room. A third wire drops to the switch on the wall. If I simply tie all the wires together the fan is permanently on and using the switch throws the breaker. If I attempt to separate the hot wires I lack power to half of the circuit.
I do know that the original installation had 4 wire nuts. How would I separate these to cause this circuit to work properly again. All 4 wires (Hot, Carry to living room, Carry to Switch, Fan) are Black/White/Ground with no extra wire.
No wires are marked. I am fairly sure this was a full-on DIY job from the 70s at best. I can separate the circuits and I know which is which so finding the white form the switch will be a non-issue. If this is the case, what do I do with the Black from the switch? My guess is I tie it with the white from the fan separately.

Old switch loops used the white to the switch as a hot wire.  If the switch has a white and black wire on the screws, then the switch white is connected to the black hots in the box/ceiling, not to the whites.  If correct, then that white is supposed to marked black or red.

Isherwood, I understood this already. It was simply included as information. I want the switch to run the light. Rather than attempt to pick something out to complain about maybe answer the actual question. I do not assume anyone on the internet knows everything about what is going on so I chose to include as much information as I could.

Crip659, I was unable to reply at first so I edited the message. I've not run into this particular situation. That said the switch is indeed wired opposite.

The black from the switch is connected to the fan black.

Thank you very much for the assistance Crip659. Your answers have solved my issue quite nicely.

Isherwood, I strongly advice you to refrain from your obvious need to troll on this website. I find it very interesting that you were so embarrassed by your original post that you chose to delete it. At this point I would direct you toward the multitude of proverbs around the world in reference to what one should do when they have nothing useful to say.

I think you're still unclear on how this site works. It's not social media. Comments are temporary, which is why I removed mine after it served its purpose. Most of these will be gone shortly (purged by the community), including the one that led you to a solution. See, crip659 has not provided an answer, as you learned when you took the [tour] and as they well know from being told many times before. This question is therefore unresolved.  Maybe get to know a network before you start throwing insults. You'll find that warnings about apparent safety concerns are quite common.

@Eric  You can provide an answer now showing what you did/found out from our comments if the question is resolved.

Are a bath fan and living room outlets allowed to share a circuit?
